# I cant add ssh to update-rc.d, says mismatch stop runlevel

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

Im trying to get ssh start as the system start so I can putty my way into it remotly.

I've tried sudo `update-rc.d ssh defaults` but ut says

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: ssh stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (none)
```

Could anyone tell me what the right command would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following command to to that:

```
$ ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc2.d/S18ssh
```

This creates a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from `/etc/init.d/ssh` to `/etc/rc2.d/S18ssh` so the computer will start the ssh server during boot.